# How to find which PHP.ini your Apache is using - Mac OS Mojave?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, apache, php-ini

I am on a **Mac OS X Mojave**. I have no idea where is the correct `php.ini` that my **Apache2** used.

I want to update the memory_limit.

I ran

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini
```

I got

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php5/lib                                                      
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

Then, I opened up `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`

set `memory_limit = 2G` and restart apache `sudo apachectl -k restart`

re-attempt `composer install`

I kept getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 126

---

**php --version**

```
PHP 7.1.4 (cli) (built: May  6 2017 10:02:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.4, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: What does composer have to do with apache?

Comment: apache is the local web server that I use on my Mac. Apache usually points to a PHP  inside the Mac, and composer use PHP, and I need to update php.ini.

Comment: You have to run phpinfo() on your webserver and not on your command-line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command line PHP and your web-server based PHP are often configured differently.

Create a temporary webpage, and then run the `phpinfo();` from there

```
#File: test.php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

**Load the file via a web browser** and you'll find your `php.ini` and any additional `ini` files listed there.

If you're seeing your memory when running PHP from the command line (your question is a little ambiguous there), then try running the following command

```
$ php --ini
```

this will list every ini file used by your command line PHP.  By bet would be one of those sets a memory limit that's overriding the one you're setting.

Comment: Alan, Is your suggestion is diff than this command that I listed on my post ? `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini `

Comment: @kyo Read his post carefully. Running PHP from the Command Line Interface (CLI) is different than accessing a web page in your browser.

Comment: @kyo Yes.  When you run PHP via the console you're running a specific binary with a specific configuration.  When you run PHP via the web server, you're actually using a completely different binary that's often compiled to look in a different place for your ini files.

Comment: Ok, I am not doubting he's wrong. I'm just checking with him if what I did will show similar result as his.

Comment: After create a test.php and added the content about, how do I run ? or go to it ?

Comment: @kyo Your question mentioned apache -- so run it however you run other web pages -- or are you seeing your memory limit error when you're running PHP on the command line?

Comment: My site won't load, if I don't have vendor folder, vendor folder generated after running composer install, which give me error of memory_list that I am trying to fix.

Comment: @kyo OK, if you're seeing the memory problems when you're using composer the web-server doesn't come into it (no need to run your apache restart).  I update the question with additional debugging instructions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a default php.ini on Mac OS X Mojave.
There was only `php.ini.default` and no other php.ini.
I copied php.ini.default to php.ini, restart apache with:
`sudo apachectl restart`

Then was loaded /etc/php.ini and visible  within the phpinfo, and php.ini can be edited.